# Test iPhone apps on Ipad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to buy iPad 4 to test apps both for iPhone 4 and 5 resolution, I know that there's no problem to test Iphone 4 apps on iPad, but what about iPhone 5?Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPad will **not** display apps running at iPhone 5 (568 pts high) size. It will only display apps running at iPhone 4 res.

The alternative to going out and buying each and every device is just using the iOS simulator instead. Contrary to what other are saying, you do **not** need a Retina display Mac - the iPhone 5 sim runs just fine on my 13-inch non-Retina MBP, and you will only need the iPhone 5 sim - the iPad can take care of all the other devices.

Answer (score 1):

You can test any apps on the iPad although the aspect will be incorrect (568 point height for i5 so you will only see the 320x480 standard version). However, what you can do is use the iOS simulator for all the different devices.

Answer (score -1):

The only way to test iPhone 4, 4S and 5 without owning the device, with retina resolution, is in the simulator on your Mac.

You also need a Mac with a Retina display if you don't want an oversized phone on the screen.

You can test both iPhone 4, 4S and 5 on an iPad 4, but not with retina resolution

Comment: Your answer contradicts itself "The only way to test iPhone 4, 4S and 5 without owning the device, with full resolution, is in the simulator on your Mac." then you go on to say "You can test both iPhone 4, 4S and 5 on an iPad 4, but not with retina resolution" so which is it. Can I or can't I?

Comment: As the answer (and your comment says), if you do not own the device, the only way to test **with retina resolution** is in the simulator, but you can test it **without retina resolution** on your iPad

Comment: Well no its not. If you have an iPad4 and you run your app on there if iPhone only it will run as if it was an iPhone4. If you wanted to test none retina you would have to test it on a none retina iPad or using the simulator. So your comment "only way to test with retina resolution is in the simulator" is not true. 'Undos` answer is completely correct this isn't.